# Parse: how to design the data structure so that showing 500K followers will be fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, data-structures, parse-platform

Hi I am working on a social project that need to show a user's followers and following. And I am using the AnyPic project as example https://parse.com/tutorials. In Anypic example, showing number of followers is easy. You just need to get a list of followers of a user and count how many are there. But my question is what if there are 500K or 1M followers, will this approach be slow? Or should we do something different. 
For example, we will still follow the anyPic example and have a class(or table) to record who is following who. And at the same time, we have an Integer column called "Number of Followers" in the user table. Everything a user follows userA, we will increment UserA's "Number of Followers". So whenever we need to know the number of followers of UserA, we can simply look at the "Number of Followers" column. But I prefer not to do it this way seems it adds some extra complexity.

Please let me know what you think about this. Or maybe Parse is so fast and powerful that I just don't need to worry about this issue at all.

Comment: No, you definitely want to do it that way with a "Number of Followers" column because it's actually *less* algorithmically complex. Also note that you can only fetch maybe 1000 PFObjects at a time... which probably won't be a huge issue since you can't actually show 500K followers on a device's screen at once.

Comment: Also, you can update the count in cloud code so it doesn't make your app any more complicated at all

Comment: check on "countQueries()"  http://blog.parse.com/2011/11/04/new-tricks-with-queries/

Comment: I know we can use "countObjectsInBackground", but it seems to me there is limitation:
Caveat: Count queries are rate limited to a maximum of 160 requests per minute. They can also return inaccurate results for classes with more than 1,000 objects. Thus, it is preferable to architect your application to avoid this sort of count operation (by using counters, for example.)

Comment: Also I am not sure the performance of "countObjectsInBackground" function if there 100K to 1M results.

Comment: Is this a real app that has to handle 1M followers (implying probably many more users)?  I doubt that any at that scale run on the parse.com free tier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've learned with Parse: some times the "dirty way" is the best choise. Do you know "Parse cloudCode"? Just use `afterSave` function to increment the number of followers.

Ps.: Choose your best strategy (Join Table or Parse Relation) based on Parse information: https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#manytomany